# Spring READ_COMMITTED gives same result after another transaction changes the value

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, transactions, spring-transactions

I am trying to test the isolation levels in spring with MySQL database. Here are my methods for updating and reading data:

```
//jpa repository
private final ProductRepository productRepository;

@Override
@Transactional
public ProductEntity update(Long id, String title, Long quantity) {
    Optional<ProductEntity> productOpt = productRepository.findById(id);
    if(productOpt.isPresent()) {
        ProductEntity product = productOpt.get();
        if(title != null) {
            product.setProductTitle(title);
        }
        if(quantity != null) {
            product.setQuantity(quantity);
        }
        productRepository.saveAndFlush(product);
        if(debug == 1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not update product.");
        }
        return product;
    }
    throw new NoSuchElementException("Could not find product with id: " + id);
}

@Override
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
public ProductEntity findByIdReadCommitted(Long id) {
    Optional<ProductEntity> productOpt = productRepository.findById(id);
    Optional<ProductEntity> productOpt2 = productRepository.findById(id);
    return productOpt.orElseThrow();
}
```

Here is the scenario. The current quantity of product is 1 at the beginning.

- Thread 1 starts, tries to read the value of the product (`productOpt = productRepository.findById(id)`) but I stop at the breakpoint and do not read the value yet.
- Thread 2 starts, tries to update the quantity of the same product to 0. It calls `saveAndFlush()`, but does not commit yet.
- Thread 1 continues, reads the value of product (`productOpt = productRepository.findById(id)`) and as expected, it shows the quantity as 1 since update transaction has not yet committed and isolation level is `READ_COMMITTED`.
- Thread 2 continues, commits the changes and when I check the value in MySQL database, I see that quantity is updated to 0.
- Thread 1 continues, tries to read the same product again (`productOpt2 = productRepository.findById(id)`), and still reads the quantity as 1.

The last step is unexpected to me. Since `READ_COMMITTED` allows non repeatable reads, I would expect to read quantity as 0 since another thread changed its value and committed. Why is the quantity equals to 0 for the second read operation? Is that because second read result is received from cache? If so, how can I test it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. The reason is, the second read brings result from the cache. So I used `entityManager.clear()` between reads to test it.

```
@Override
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
public ProductEntity findByIdReadCommitted(Long id) {
    Optional<ProductEntity> productOpt = productRepository.findById(id);
    entityManager.clear(); // clear the cache
    Optional<ProductEntity> productOpt2 = productRepository.findById(id);
    return productOpt.orElseThrow();
}
```